# Determine name/alphabet range based on count of records and number of bins/groups in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a SQL query that returns a data set of a population of people. The data set includes a person's name and various other fields specific to the person.

I have a team of individuals who are assigned to do work on each of the person records where the person records are grouped by last name, e.g. team member 1 works on persons with last names starting with A to D, team member 2 works on E to I, etc.

I would like to distribute the population evenly between the team members while maintaining the name groups in full, i.e. all persons with a last name starting with D will be assigned to a team member and will not be split between two team members.

My normal process for doing this job would be to find the total number of persons in the population and divide it by the number of team members. This would give me a reference value. I then would organize my population of names as a running total by name in alphabetical order; e.g. A = 32, B = 19, C = 50, etc. Then I would start with A and continue adding letter groups until the count of persons gets as close as possible to the reference value. This would give me the first cutoff/group of names. For example, if my reference value were 100, then I would group together A + B + C +...n until the count of persons within the letter groups gets as close to 100 as possible such as persons with names A to D totals to 103 (this is just an example). Then I would continue from that point adding the reference value to where I left off and continue adding letters until I get to the next cutoff; from the previous example, I would add 100 to 103, therefore my next cutoff group would be around 203 on the running total. I would repeat this process until all letter groups are assigned to a team member.

I have included an example distribution of names. In this example there are 478 total persons in the population. If I have four team members working on this population, an even split would be 119.5 (478/4). Because I do not want to split the name groups, each team member will get different numbers of persons assigned to them in order to maintain the continuity of the name group and the alphabetical order. In this example, Team Member 1 gets 124 persons, Team Member 2 gets 106 persons, Team Member 3 gets 112, and Team Member 4 gets the remaining persons. Therefore the name ranges for each team member are:

Team Member 1: A to E

Team Member 2: F to L

Team Member 3: M to Q

Team Member 4: R to Z

Is it possible to have a Power BI report perform this process and automatically adjust the groupings based on the user's input for the number of team members and/or slicer selections? So if a user of the report were to filter the population to only show people with a specific type of health insurance, for example, it would adjust the totals and grouping based on that filtered population.

[image: Example Distribution]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a calculated column to group the data into "clusters" based on the first letter of the lastname column:

```
Cluster Number = 
VAR NumClusters = 4
VAR LetterRank = RANKX(ALL('names'[lastname]), 'names'[lastname], , ASC)
RETURN
    DIVIDE(LetterRank - 1, COUNTROWS('names') / NumClusters) + 1
```

Each row is assigned to one of four clusters based on the first letter of the lastname column. Then use this calculated column in other calculations or visualizations.

nb: the above is untested.

In reality I would prefer to approach this using SQL (TSQL used in the following example)

```
DECLARE @numclusters integer = 4;

WITH clusters AS (
  SELECT
        LEFT(lastname, 1) AS letter
      , NTILE(@numclusters) OVER (ORDER BY LEFT(lastname, 1)) AS cluster_number
  FROM names
  GROUP BY
       LEFT(lastname, 1)
   )
SELECT
      names.*
    , c.cluster_number
    , count(*) over(partition by cluster_number) cluster_rows
FROM names
JOIN clusters c ON LEFT(names.lastname, 1) = c.letter
ORDER BY lastname
;
```

see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/asO-Lehb

Comment: Thank you. I too like the TSQL solution. However, in my situation, I will not be able to declare the number of clusters outright. The clusters will actually be dependent on any filter or slicer selection the user may set. For example, I would have a slicer (and a table with the slicer values) that contains values 2 to 10 and the user would select one of those values to declare the number of clusters. Then I would like the measure you suggested to use that user's input to perform the calculation. How could I reference the user's input in the measure calculation?

Comment: nb: `var NumClusters` I have provided a means to consume a parameter value (in both sets of code) - it's now up to you to send that into the code. You could ask more questions on how to do that. but for example a "report parameter" might work - or you perform some other calculation to arrive at that number. Do remember I can only see this question, and stackoverflow isn't a way to get full consulting services.